# Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-drive-api

I have run the code you have given on google qiuck start to upload File,now when it runs ,it gives me this error,plz help me.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}

    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:978)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeUploadInitiation(MediaHttpUploader.java:338)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:252)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.executeUnparsed(Drive.java:309)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.execute(Drive.java:331)
```

Comment: Can you paste your code here?